# Is there any way to avoid ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using multiple ng-repeats in the ionic view to show json data, i can get the data in console in no time but I guess having multiple ng-repeats has slowed the perform altogether, which cause the app to freeze and takes a minute or so for the data to appear on the view.

Is there an alternate way , to avoid speed up the performance. ?

Comment: Load data partially.

Comment: Watch here: http://www.williambrownstreet.net/blog/2013/07/angularjs-my-solution-to-the-ng-repeat-performance-problem/

Comment: why dont u use quick-ng-repeat https://github.com/allaud/quick-ng-repeat

Comment: If my answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [collection-repeat](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/).

`collection-repeat` allows an app to show huge lists of items much more
 performant than `ng-repeat`.